# Tomcat log rotation without file renaming

Tags: tomcat, logging, logrotate

I have tomcat setup to create 100 log files, with each file being 5MBs. One of the things that bothers me is that tomcat will rename every file, once the file being written currently reaches its size limit. Assume a basename of `myFile.log`, `myFile.log.98` will be moved `myFile.log.99` (overwriting `myFile.log.99`), `myFile.log.97` will be moved to `myFile.log.98` ... and finally `myFile.log` will be `myFile.log.1`, and a new `myFile.log` is created. That is a lot of renames to go through.

I want to change this renaming strategy to the following: Persist a number, say `n`, which is incremented each time we have a log rotation. Move the current file, `myFile.log`, to `myFile.log.<n>`, and remove the file `myFile.log.<n-100>`, if any. Two file system operations. The latest is always the one with the highest number. No renaming to be done.

- Is there a rolling strategy to implement that (or something that achieves my goal of no renaming)
- If not, can I implement a class that overrides the original roller
- Finally, is this an unreasonable thing to ask (I.e., so unimportant that should not think about it)

Thanks.

Comment: How have you configured the file rolling and exactly which log file are you doing this to?

Comment: I configured logging in my app's log4j.properties file.

Comment: So this is application logging, rather than anything to do with Tomcat. You may get more help if you recast your question as a log4j question rather than a Tomcat question. A quick look at the log4j Javadoc suggests that the current behaviour is by design but that you could implement your own RollingAppender if you wished.